# Could URLClassLoader be approperiate for SPI?

Tags: java, spi

I'm trying to load a jar at runtime by `URLClassLoader` through Service Provider API. However, it turns out a failure.

Following are what I've done:

1. Create a module named `shadow-plugin-api`, which contains interface `com.github.soiff.shadow.api.Plugin` to be implemented by plugin;
2. Create a implementation of `shadow-plugin-api` named `shadow-plugin` and packaged as `shadow-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, the implementation class is `com.github.soiff.shadow.plugin.SpringPlugin`;
3. Create spring boot application named `shadow-core` and include `shadow-plugin-api`;
4. Load `shadow-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` by `URLClassLoader` dynamically and try to load my `com.github.soiff.shadow.plugin.SpringPlugin` through `ServiceLoader` but it gets nothing.

My git repository is : https://github.com/soiff/soiff-shadow.

I've tried following solution, but still could not make it work. Please give me some advice, thanks in advance!

1. I've tried abstract class instead of interface of my SPI interface and change it back to interface when I could not achieve my goal;
2. I've tried `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` to get resource and pass my `URLClassLoader` as the input parameter but it did not work;
3. I've tried `ResourceFinder` implemented by Apache and it could not find proper resource neither;

My question is how could I load resources from an external jar by `URLClassLoader`? Could SPI be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simple, the answer is yes.

And you may curious about what was going wrong, good question, the answer is `URLClassLoader`. But how? `URLClassLoader` is good enough to handle this with each items you've put it. In other words, there could be as many items as you've put into your `URLClassLoader` by parameter `urls`. So, if you want to make it work, you need to uncompress your external jar to a specified directory and add all items extracted to your `URLClassLoader` by input parameter `urls` as:

```
loader = new URLClassLoader(list.toArray(new URL[0]));
```

Where `list` contains all items.

Maybe there is other good solution, but this is just working for me. It's appreciate that if any guy could post another better solution for this. Thanks in advance!

By the way, this solution is based on `Hadoop` project. Thanks for the excellent project of `Apache Hadoop Work Team`.