# Calling Spring Main Method from Another Class Error

Tags: spring, plugins, openfire

I am working on a Plugin for an OpenFire Server. I am trying to integrate Spring into this plugin. When the plugin is initialized, I will like to call the Main Method for my Spring.

When I execute the Spring alone, it works fine, but when I call its main method from my plugin, I get an exception.
How am I suppose to call the Spring Main Method.
What am I missing. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Spring Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            System.out.println("No error");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);

        }

    }
}
```

OpenFire Plugin:

```
public class FetchNewsPlugin implements Plugin {

    @Override
    public void initializePlugin(PluginManager manager, File pluginDirectory) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 String[] args = {};
                Application.main(args);
             }
         };

         new Thread(r).start();
         System.out.println("Plugin Intitialized");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyPlugin() {
    }

}
```

Log Output:

> Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
>       at hello.Application.main(Application.java:11)
>       at org.clinton.openfire.plugin.FetchNewsPlugin$1.run(FetchNewsPlugin.java:20)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 3 more

Where Exception is being thrown:

```
 /**
     * Finds and loads the class with the specified name from the URL search
     * path. Any URLs referring to JAR files are loaded and opened as needed
     * until the class is found.
     *
     * @param name the name of the class
     * @return the resulting class
     * @exception ClassNotFoundException if the class could not be found,
     *            or if the loader is closed.
     * @exception NullPointerException if {@code name} is {@code null}.
     */
    protected Class findClass(final String name)
        throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        final Class result;
        try {
            result = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction>() {
                    public Class run() throws ClassNotFoundException {
                        String path = name.replace('.', '/').concat(".class");
                        Resource res = ucp.getResource(path, false);
                        if (res != null) {
                            try {
                                return defineClass(name, res);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new ClassNotFoundException(name, e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }, acc);
        } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException pae) {
            throw (ClassNotFoundException) pae.getException();
        }
        if (result == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/clinton/git/Openfire/bin/build/lib/ant/slf4j-simple.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/clinton/git/Openfire/bin/build/lib/dist/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/clinton/git/Openfire/build/lib/ant/slf4j-simple.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/clinton/git/Openfire/build/lib/dist/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `URLClassLoader` to load classes that your needed. However, an `URLClassLoader` should contain all items or jars it depends on not only the jar itself.

In other words, you'd better extract your jar and add all necessary items to your `URLClassLoader`.

In this way it should work. And please let me know if any problem.

And question https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339725/5619827 could be helpful.

Comment: I don't think, I am using any URLClassLoader. I have not touched anything of that name o:o. If you require my pom.xml, let me know I will add it. Thank you

Comment: I have seen the method from the URLClassLoader where the exception is being thrown. Please check the updated question.

Comment: When I run the same project alone, it works, it stops working when it is called by the Plugin class. :(

Comment: Could you show me your URLClassLoader codes? I mean how to use it.

Comment: Yes, so I give you my answer.

Comment: You run it in your plugin, the difference is the class loader. The most probably reason is you do not load all of the classes and libraries into your URLClassLoader. So please check it or just publish your project if you do not know how to fix.

Comment: The URLClassLoader was not created by me. This is part of Java Core Libraries. Its documentation is here [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html] . I am adding the rest of my codes to the question. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Would you please post the ucp list about this class loader? And you can debug it and verify the items.

Comment: I tried a little debugging. Please take a look at the erros, I found. It seems to me that, they are part of the OpenFire Source Code.

Comment: ANd can you tell me what ucp list mean ? :)

Comment: I mean check the contained items of each class loader, such as `URLClassLoader#ucp`.

Comment: My dear brother, can you please still explain more on what I am to do here. Still can't figure it out.:) Thanks

Comment: I mean you can debug `URLClassLoader#getURLs()` and check whether the resource you need is here.

Comment: At getURL() execution: Properties of ucp: closed=false, jarHandler=Handler(id=85), lmap = Hashmap<k,V>, loaders=ArrayList<E>, lookupCacheLoaders=null, lookupCacheURLs=null, path=ArrayList<E>, url=Stack<E>, elementCount=0, capacityIncrement=0, modCount=20, elementData = Object [10]

Comment: After the getURLs(), when I stepinto, I get this "Class File Editor", "Source not found" Window.

Comment: URLClassPath.getURLs() line: 170 [local variables unavailable]

Comment: @ClintonYeboah So the resource you are trying to load is there?

Comment: My dear brother, I was able to find a workaround, please check my answer. Thank you. I do not have enough points to mark your answer. But thanks...

Comment: Congratulations, this is also what I wish you to do to check the items hold by class loader. Of course, you fail to check it by debugging but packaging them together into one single jar.

Comment: I am quiet new to Eclipse. Started using it in less than a week. I used it because the only guide available for setting up OpenFire Server is with Eclipse. However, I am good with linux commands, so I created a jar with "maven clean install". It did the rest for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gemini for helping, but I guess I was too dumb to follow his way. I found another workaround: Since the Spring could start successfully when executed alone. I bundled the Spring into a runnable jar file and executed using the following when th plugin starts:

```
private void startSpring() {
    try {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java", "-jar", 
            "/home/clinton/git/Maven/target/mavenproject2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
    processBuilder.directory(new File("/home/clinton/git/Maven/Working"));
    File log = new File("log");
     processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
     processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
     Process p = processBuilder.start();
     assert processBuilder.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
     assert processBuilder.redirectOutput().file() == log;
     assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
    System.out.println("Started success");

        //Process p = processBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone too. I always find a way :)

Comment: So which means, you are really not put the necessary libraries into your jar? This chould be found easily if you checked your class loader's items. But congratulations, anyway.

Comment: Modified. According Oracle Examples found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html